# FileStream (jpeg from pdf converter) to Byte[]

Tags: c#, byte, jpeg, filestream

Using aspose, I have converted the first page of a pdf document to a jpeg (to be used as a thumbnail in a 'Documents' section to one of my asp.net pages). This is, upto this point, stored in a FileStream - but I need a byte array to assign to the datavalue of an Image control. Can anyone point me in the right direction to converting this? I've had a good look around and I can't find the solution.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

`byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes("path/to/file.jpg")`

Comment: I'm not actually saving the jpg though, and I preferably don't want to have to. Thanks.

EDIT: There isn't actually a ReadAllBytes method anyway.

Comment: Yes, there is. Not on `FileStream`, but on `File`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var memStream = new MemoryStream();
yourFileStream.CopyTo(memStream);
var bytes = memStream.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this....

```
     /// <summary>
/// Function to get byte array from a file
/// </summary>
/// <param name="_FileName">File name to get byte array</param>
/// <returns>Byte Array</returns>
public byte[] FileToByteArray(string _FileName)
{
    byte[] _Buffer = null;

    try
    {
        // Open file for reading
        System.IO.FileStream _FileStream = new System.IO.FileStream(_FileName, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);

        // attach filestream to binary reader
        System.IO.BinaryReader _BinaryReader = new System.IO.BinaryReader(_FileStream);

        // get total byte length of the file
        long _TotalBytes = new System.IO.FileInfo(_FileName).Length;

        // read entire file into buffer
        _Buffer = _BinaryReader.ReadBytes((Int32)_TotalBytes);

        // close file reader
        _FileStream.Close();
        _FileStream.Dispose();
        _BinaryReader.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception _Exception)
    {
        // Error
        Console.WriteLine("Exception caught in process: {0}", _Exception.ToString());
    }

    return _Buffer;
}
```